# AS3 use one variable to load all movieclip

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash

is there a way to make all the movieclip that I want to load on stage into an array?

```
if (selectDiffText.text == "Collection 1 Easy")
    {
        var c1_easy:cartoonEasy = new cartoonEasy();
        addChild(c1_easy);
        c1_easy.x = 412;
        c1_easy.y = 400;
        TweenMax.from(c1_easy, 0.5, {alpha:0, ease:Expo.easeOut});
    }
    else if (selectDiffText.text == "Collection 1 Medium")
    {
        var c1_medium:cartoonMedium = new cartoonMedium();
        addChild(c1_medium);
        c1_medium.x = 412;
        c1_medium.y = 400;
        TweenMax.from(c1_medium, 0.5, {alpha:0, ease:Expo.easeOut});
    }
    else if (selectDiffText.text == "Collection 1 Hard")
    {
        var c1_hard:cartoonHard = new cartoonHard();
        addChild(c1_hard);
        c1_hard.x = 412;
        c1_hard.y = 400;
        TweenMax.from(c1_hard, 0.5, {alpha:0, ease:Expo.easeOut});
    }
else{trace("ERROR!")}
```

now I have 3 movieclip in library which is cartoonEasy, cartoonMedium and cartoonHard.
I'll add one of them into stage but with different variable.
is it a way I can make them just using ONE variable only? is it using array?

because if just using 1 variable then i can easily control object inside 1 of the movieclip that I called from library.

what I'm thinking is like this:

```
var c1_all:cartoonAll = new cartoonEasy() = new cartoonMedium() = new cartoonHard()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function addCartoon( obj:* ):void{ // might change * to DisplayObject
    addChild(obj);
    obj.x = 412;
    obj.y = 400;
    TweenMax.from(obj, 0.5, {alpha:0, ease:Expo.easeOut});
}

var obj:*;
switch (selectDiffText.text ){ // use switch since it is clean code
  case "Collection 1 Easy":
    obj = new cartoonEasy();
  case "Collection 1 Medium":
    obj = new cartoonMedium();
  case "Collection 1 Hard":
    obj = new cartoonHard();
  default:
    trace("ERROR!")
}
if( obj ){
  addCartoon( obj );
}






// manipulating obj will change the item on stage.
obj.x = 500;
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed an Array could be used.

```
var c1All:Array = [
    new cartoonEasy(),
    new cartoonMedium(),
    new cartoonHard()
];
```

To apply your code to all of these objects you can do this:

```
for each(var i:MovieClip in c1All)
{
    addChild(i);
    i.x = 412;
    i.y = 400;
    TweenMax.from(i, 0.5, {alpha:0, ease:Expo.easeOut});
}
```

PS I suggest using `throw new Error("message");` rather than `trace("error")`.

Comment: but this will add in all the MC...what I need is just 1 of the MC only to the stage...

Comment: @pizza0502 Then you can just do `addChild(c1All[0]);` to add the first, `c1All[1]` for the second, etc.